# Integration of landau symbols w.r.t. kernel/probability density functions

Tags: probability, integration

I'm trying to understand:

Let $K$ be a non-negative-valued kernel function of order two such that it's first moment is equal to zero and it's second moment is finite, $p$ be probability density function that has$k > 2$ continuous derivatives that are ultimately monotone.It's $r+2$th derivative is continuos and square integrable. Furthermore let $h = h_n$ be positive valued sequence of bandwidths such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h = 0, ~ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nh^{(2r +1)} = \infty$, and $r$ is even.$K_h(z) := h^{-1}K(z/h)$

If we have

$E(K_h^{(r)} (X_1 - X_2)) = \int \int K(u) p(y + hu)p^{(r)}(y)dudy$

and use the Taylor Expansion

$p(y + hu) = p(y) +hup'(y) + 1/2 h^2 u^2 p''(y) + O(h^3)$

to integrate term by term, then why it is possible to estimate the integral containing $O(h^3)$ by $O(h^3)$ again, so

$E(K_h^{(r)}(X_1 - X_2)) = (\int K(u)du)(\int p^{(r)}(y)p(y)dy) + h(\int u K(u)du)(\int p^{(r)}(y)p'(y)dy) + 1/2 ~ h^2(\int u^2 K(u)du)(\int p^{(r)}(y)p''(y)dy) + O(h^3)$?

I have the same problem for

$E(K_h^{(r)} (X_1 - X_2)^2) = \int \int K^{(r)}(u)^2 p(y + hu)p(y)dudy = \frac{1}{h^{2r +1}} \int p(y)^2 dy \int K^{(r)}(u)^2 + o(\frac{1}{h^{2r +1}})$,

where the Taylor Expansion $p(y + hu) = p(y) + o(1)$ is used.

Can someone explain me why Integration has no effect on the Landau sequences? 
The calculations are from Raykar's "Very fast optimal bandwidth selection for univariate kernel density estimation".